# Why did I get HTML 404 error while view and action method exists?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, view, http-status-code-404, action

In my project, I added action method in SistemGaleri controller and then put related view. 
Action method name: GaleriIslemleri
View Name: GaleriIslemleri.cshtml which is located on View/SistemGaleri folder

```
    public ActionResult GaleriIslemleri()
    {
        var sistemGaleriDosyaAramaKriter = new SistemGaleriDosyaAramaKriter();
        try
        {

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //HelperUtils.CmsLogger.Error(ex, "Duyuru/Liste");
        }


        return View();
    }
```

Comment: put here your address url and check rout config in start up.

Comment: @hassan.ef Normally this is my url: localhost:4850/SistemGaleri/GaleriIslemleri but my project consists of a lot of modules, and i did not see defined url in route config for every module.

Comment: How do you set up routing in your app? Attribute-based or convention-based?

Comment: it depend about your project, how do you set up routing?

Comment: @vasily.sib convention based routing but every module did not set up on route config. I dont think that problem depends on route config. I did not faced the problem other modules

Comment: Can you show us how do you setup your routes?

Comment: @vasily.lib you can check out my config file on below comment

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{query}",
            defaults: new { controller = "AnaSayfa", action = "Index", query = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dosya",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}/{query}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", query = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { Id = "\\d+" }
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Dosya Duzenle History",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{query}/{ishistory}/{Id}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Dosya", action = "DosyaDuzenle", ishistory = UrlParameter.Optional, query = UrlParameter.Optional },
       constraints: new { Id = "\\d+" }
 );

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Dosya Versiyon Ekle",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}/{query}/{ParentRaporId}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Dosya", action = "DosyaVersiyonEkle", query = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { Id = "\\d+", ParentRaporId = "\\d+" }
        );


        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "History",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{ishistory}/{query}",
           defaults: new { controller = "AnaSayfa", action = "Index", ishistory = UrlParameter.Optional, query = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "raporPaylasim",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{kod}/{tarih}/{optional}",
           defaults: new
           {
               controller = "Rapor",
               action = "RaporPaylasim"
               ,
               kod = UrlParameter.Optional
               ,
               tarih = UrlParameter.Optional
               ,
               optional = UrlParameter.Optional
           }
           ///, constraints: new { kategoriKod = "[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+" }
       );
    }
}
```

@vasily.lib you can check out my config file